# jmeter command line option doesnt pick my params

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Why my command below doesn't pick the values I give at runtime rather it takes from my JMeter test plan itself where I defined with option `${__P(param1,value)}`

`<path to jmeter bat> -n -t <jmx loc> -l <loc of result.csv> -j <path to jmeterlog> -Gparam1=paramval1 -Gparam2=paramval2 -Gparam3=paramval3 -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.label=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.time=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.time=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true` -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -e -o

I am running this from jenkins. Why it is not picking up my parameters?

Comment: I tried this -J option first and then i saw some post where they suggesting to use -G option when we are sending more parameters

Comment: Right now i am using only one machine to run 120 users

Comment: like i define number of users in a variable and gave 10. During command line run, if i give 120 then it is supposed to take this 120 as input and run 120 users. This is not happening and still it runs for 10 users only

Answer (score 0):

-G is used for [distributed testing/Remote JMeter servers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

> defines a JMeter property to be sent to all remote servers.

Use `-J` instead to define JMeter property

> -J[prop_name]=[value]
> defines a local JMeter property.

Comment: this doesnt work. i tried both the options at first J and later G. So wondering if my command itself have some issue

Comment: @George move `-t` option to the end of command

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `-J` command-line argument, `-G` is for **sending the properties to JMeter Slaves** in case of [Distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

[image]

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)